# mvn release plugin doesn't update included pom file

Tags: maven, release

the maven release plugin doesn't update the pom files which are included:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
....
....
<configuration>
<projectsDirectory>.</projectsDirectory>
<streamLogs>true</streamLogs>
<pomIncludes>
  <pomInclude>pomDisContainer.xml</pomInclude>
</pomIncludes>
```

how can i force the release plugin to update all my pom.xml files?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking at this from the wrong direction. Would a better solution be to have the [Maven Invoker Plugin update the invoked `pom.xml` files every time instead](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/run-mojo.html#filterProperties)?

The Invoker plugin will automatically replace properties in the pom, providing they are using the alternative syntax:

```
@project.version@
```

Will be replaced by the *invoking* project's version.